# How to create an auto-incrementing non-key field

Tags: entity-framework

I have a field on an entity that needs to be an auto-incrementing integer but is **not** the entity key (I use guids for that).

How do I decorate the field to make it an auto-incrementing id?

```
public class Foo {
    public Guid Id {get; private set;} = Guid.NewGuid();
    public int ShouldAutoIncrement {get; private set;}
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the int value if the Guid is the key?

Comment: @Nate client request, they want to be able to be able to talk about this one particular entity by a friendly incremented number. My entire infrastructure works with guid ids though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework auto incrementing field, that isnt the Id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427540/entity-framework-auto-incrementing-field-that-isnt-the-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the related questions ([Entity Framework auto incrementing field, that isn't the Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427540/entity-framework-auto-incrementing-field-that-isnt-the-id?rq=1)) is answered by the use of the

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

annotation