# Entity Framework Core 2.0 autoincrement and primary key mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am working on converting a database-first project to code-first.

I have the following class and I am using EF Core 2.0:

```
public class WorkUser
{
    public int WorkUserId { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

I tried the following and not sure whether it is correct.

```
public class WorkUser
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int WorkUserId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

I want the `WorkUserId` as an autoincrement property and `UserId` as primary key. The `UserId` value is coming from another table. So want this to be primary key but without autoincrement.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Have you actually tried your code? What does it generate?

Comment: What is `BaseEntity`? Are you having problems, if so what are they? Right now, this isn't really a question.

Comment: This [should work as you expect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10427810/33051) but you will need to ensure that you're setting the `UserId` to a valid, unique value. If this table has a many-to-many relationship you'll need [a composite key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19792295/33051) formed of both the `UserId` and the `WorkUserId` (i.e. add a `Key` attribute and a `Column` attribute with an `Order` property.)

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid Thanks. this table is not going to have many-to-many relationship.

Comment: @DavidG i have updated by removing the baseentity.

Comment: Have you considered using EF Core Power Tools?

Answer (score 2):

The following worked as i expected:

```
public class WorkUser
{
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int WorkUserId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public class SampleContext:DBContext{
public DbSet<WorkUser> WorkUsers{ get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder){
    modelBuilder.Entity<WorkUser>()
        .Property(p => p.WorkUserId )
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In EF Core you should use the Sequence for the solution.

```
    public class Project
    {
      [Key]
      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    }
```

And than you configure your onModelBuilder:

```
modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("ProjectId").StartsAt(100).IncrementsBy(1);
modelBuilder.Entity< Project>().Property(o => o.ProjectId).HasDefaultValueSql("NEXT VALUE FOR ProjectId");
```

or you can read more on the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/sequences).